# HTTP timeout from an EC2 instance when I call a python API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to call a [python api](https://github.com/swar/nba_api) from an EC2 instance that I have configured with Ubuntu. When I run the file locally on my computer it works, but when I run the same file on my EC2 instance, I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443, timeout=20)
```

Here is my file. The calls to my mongodb work on the EC2 instance, but the stats_nba API endpoint does not work.

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import commonplayerinfo
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests
import time

cluster = MongoClient("My Mongo Server")
db = cluster['nba_data']
collection = db["players"]
addCol = db['playerCommonInfo']

players = collection.find({})

ids = []
pastIds = []

for player in players:

    ids.append(player['_id'])

previousInfo = addCol.find({})

for prev in previousInfo:

    pastIds.append(prev['_id'])

headers = {
    'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

print("Getting Player Info...")

for person in ids:

    if person not in pastIds:

        try:
            # the line where the error occurs on my EC2 Instance
            player_info = commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player_id=person, headers=headers, timeout=50)

            h = player_info.common_player_info.get_dict()['headers']
            h[0] = '_id'

            d = player_info.common_player_info.get_dict()['data']

            dict1 = dict(zip(h, d[0]))
            addCol.insert_one(dict1)

            print (dict1['DISPLAY_FIRST_LAST'])

            time.sleep(6)

        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            print("Read Timeout")
            print("Waiting 1 min until retry")
            time.sleep(60)


print("finished")
```

I have configured my Security Settings on my EC2 instance to be open to http and https traffic. [image]

Is this some type of error with my EC2 network settings? I can't find any resources pointing me in te right direction.

Comment: It should be simple enought to determine whether you can reach the internet from your EC2 machine. Just point requests at google.com (or SSH on to the machine and use curl). Assuming that works - which I expect it will - is it possible that the API is geographically restricted or has blacklisted the EC2 location for any reason?

Comment: I just tried executing `curl google.com` in my EC2 terminal, and it worked.

Comment: I am wondering if you get the answer for above.. I am facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

In security groups settings , https with port 443  rule is not added. Could you add https and try again.

Comment: Doesn't `All Traffic and Port Range(0-65535)` option covers all(HTTP, HTTPS, SSH etc.)?

Comment: Yes.. you are correct. All traffic and port range should cover. Your Security Group is fine. Just check once any Iptables firewall rules in your instance. Or any SSL related certificates are blocking in instance.